# How do I time a specific command?

Tags: shell, time-utility

(The linux equivalent of TimeThis.exe)

Something like:

```
timethis wget foo.com
Receiving foo.com  
...

wget foo.com took 3 seconds.
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Try just `time` instead of `timethis`.

Although be aware that there's often a shell builtin version of time *and* a binary version, which will give results in different formats:

```
$ time wget -q -O /dev/null https://unix.stackexchange.com/

real    0m0.178s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s
```

vs

```
$ \time wget -q -O /dev/null https://unix.stackexchange.com/
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.17elapsed 4%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+613minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Unlike your "timethis" program, you get three values back. That's broken down in [What is "system time" when using "time" in command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131851/what-is-system-time-when-using-time-in-command-line), but in short: *real* means "wall-clock time", while *user* and *sys* show CPU clock time, split between regular code and system calls.

Answer (score 45):

By using the executable `time` instead of the shell builtin, you can specify the output format and values. E.g. get the real elapsed time together with the command name and parameters

```
/usr/bin/time --format='%C took %e seconds' sleep 3
sleep 3 took 3.00 seconds
```

Note that you *must* specify the path for `time`, else you will default to using the shell built-in. You can also use `command time` or `\time` to execute the utility instead of the build-in.

Comment: notice that: the path is important. Don't just use 'time' in bash.  Instead, use /usr/bin/time

Comment: what's the difference if `/usr/bin` is in their PATH?

Comment: @galois The difference is that without the explicit path, the shell's built-in `time` utility will be used.

Answer (score 2):

@galois :
The various shells have a handful of "built-in" commands which take precedence over anything in the path.  Normally this is advantageous; the built-ins will tend to run faster (because not calling an external file) and typically give the desired result (i.e., in the case of time command you normally do not care which version you are using, unless you want to use the "--format" flag).

So "time" without any special characters (like /) to make it look like a path will end up running the built-in, regardless of what your PATH looks like.

To force the shell to use the external time command, you must provide the path