# How to treat a string of a file as a value when run awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/al2helal/ThesisWork/master/consecutive7pointDown10.input) that has some missing data point's value and the missing value are shown as `****`. I need to select rows having consecutive 7 columns with value less than 10. When I run my [script](https://github.com/al2helal/ThesisWork/blob/master/consecutive7pointDown10) it also gives those rows that have `****` in consecutive columns.

I can solve it easily by replacing all `****`  with a higher value. But, I don't want to change my input file. I want to do something so that my script treat `****` as a number(greater than `10 i.e. str=****=100`). How can I do that?

sample input `consecutive7pointDown10.input`-

```
2     3    4    5    6    7    8   0  12   14   23
2     3    4    12   6    7    8   0  1     2   23
**** **** **** **** **** **** **** 8 ****  **** 12
```

My script's result `consecutive7pointDown10.output`-

```
2     3    4    5    6    7    8    0    12    14   23
**** **** **** **** **** **** ****  8   ****  ****  12
```

But, expected output

```
2     3    4    5    6    7    8    0    12  14   23
```

My script `consecutive7pointDown10` is as follows-

```
#!/bin/bash
########################################################################################################################
# This script results rows having at most 10°C in consecutive at most 7 points.
# input = scriptname.input
# output = scriptname.output
########################################################################################################################
input=`basename "$0"`.input
output=`basename "$0"`.output
awk '{
    for(i=4;i<=34-6;i++)
        {   
            if($i<=10 && $(i+1)<=10 && $(i+2)<=10 && $(i+3)<=10 && $(i+4)<=10 && $(i+5)<=10 && $(i+6)<=10)
            {
                print
                next
            }
        }
}' $input > $output
```

Comment: how about completely skipping lines having `****`? or is there a case where such lines can still have 7 consecutive columns less than 10 and you want that in output?

Comment: you could temporarily change input line (won't change input file) by using `gsub(/\*{4}/,100)` before the for-loop

Comment: @Sundeep yes, I am finding this type. I will try this. I will notify you.

Comment: @Sundeep doesn't give right answer. [script image](https://imgur.com/a/HlCbu) [output image](https://imgur.com/a/Cyd75)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` as following to avoid repeating checking 7 consecutive columns by using a flag to increment when those all meet the condition, or reset it when opposite otherwise.

```bsh
awk '{c=0; split($0,arr,/ +/);
    for(x in arr) if(arr[x]<10 && arr[x]>=0) {
        if(++c==7){ print $0; next } }else{c=0} }' infile
```

Here we used [awk's split function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) «`split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])`» to split the lines (The `$0` represent the whole line in `awk`) into the array named `arr` separated by one or more spaces.

Next loop over array elements and checking if its value is between 10 and 0 then increment a flag called `c` and print the line if it's reached to 7 (means 7 consecutive elements (columns) meet the condition); Otherwise rest the flag with 0.

---

Or doing the same way without splitting the line into array.

```bsh
awk '{c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i<10 && $i>=0) {
    if(++c==7){ print $0; next } }else{c=0} }' infile
```

---

In your case as you are going to filter start from column#4 to the end, then you would need something like. The `NF` represent the number of fields/column in each line proceed by `awk`.

```
$ time awk '{c=0; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) if($i<10 && $i>=0) {
    if(++c==7) {print $0; next} }else{c=0} }' infile
real    0m0.317s
user    0m0.156s
sys     0m0.172s
```

---

Or in regex mode, again applied on your [Original file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/al2helal/ThesisWork/master/consecutive7pointDown10.input) where it contains only floating point numbers, you can use below `grep` command which is more efficient and ~6 times faster than `awk` (Where used with `-P` flag, see [Grep -E, Sed -E - low performance when '[x]{1,9999}' is used, but why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/960557/283843)), but considering flexibility of `awk` solution as you can change the ranges + will work if Integer/Float/mixed of both numbers.

```
$ time grep -P '([^\d]\d\.\d[^\d]){7}' infile
real    0m0.060s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Or in another way:

```
$ time grep -P '(\s+\d\.\d\s+){7}' infile
real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Or compatibility in `grep`, `sed` or `awk`:

```
$ time grep -E '([^0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][^0-9]){7}' infile
real    0m0.419s
user    0m0.375s
sys     0m0.063s
```

```
$ time sed -En '/([^0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][^0-9]){7}/p' infile
real    0m0.367s
user    0m0.172s
sys     0m0.203s
```

```
$ time awk '/([^0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][^0-9]){7}/' infile
real    0m0.361s
user    0m0.219s
sys     0m0.172s
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67580/discussion-between-s-and-minimax).

Comment: I think your answer should be this `awk '{ for(i=4;i<=34;i++) if($i<10 && $i>=0){if(++c==7) print $0;next}else{c=0}}' infile` instead of `awk '{ for(i=4;i<=34;i++) if($i<10 && $i>=0){if(++c==7) print $0}else{c=0}}' infile`

Comment: and `.......;next;c=0`. Am I right?

Comment: Nop, in this case `c=0` will never run.

Comment: I add `c=0` in starting for each row, otherwise it increments previous `c's` value when `c<7` in previous row. `awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)if($i<10 && $i>=0){if(++c==7) {print $0;c=0;next}}else{c=0}}' infile` result one row, but it is not true for this [data](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25810903/)

Comment: @alhelal, please check my updates which it works now even for your [another data shared sample](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25810903/).

Comment: You didn't explain the `time`?

Comment: That's used for [getting time cost once output of a command resulted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10745/72456).

Comment: why [this script](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25822785/)(although about similar as you) results nothing for  [this data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/al2helal/ThesisWork/master/consecutive7pointDown10.input)?. There may be a silly error that was not found by me.

Comment: Hi, it's not same, in yours the `else` statement is for inner `if` while it must be for outer `if` statement. see mine above.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/(\<[0-9]\s+){7}/{print}' input.txt
```

or

```
sed -rn '/(\b[0-9]\s{1,}){7}/p' input.txt
```

will do the job.

**Explanation for the awk (the same logic for the sed):**

- `/(\<[0-9]\s+){7}/{print}` - print lines containing the pattern.
- `\<` - Matches a word boundary; that is it matches if the character to the right is a “word” character and the character to the left is a “non-word” character.
- `[0-9]\s+` - one digit from `0` to `9`, then one or more spaces.
- `(\<[0-9]\s+){7}` - matches, if the `\<[0-9]\s+` pattern is repeated seven times.

**Input**

```
2     3    4    5    6    7    8   0  12   14   23
2     3    4    12   6    7    8   0  1     2   23
**** **** **** **** **** **** **** 8 ****  **** 12
```

**Output**

```
2     3    4    5    6    7    8   0  12   14   23
```

#### EDIT:

For floating numbers with the one digit precision (9.2, 8.1, 7.5, etc).

```
awk '/(\<[0-9]\.[0-9](\s+|$)){7}/{print}' input.txt
```

Comment: Clever way! But assuming the values are always in single digit, but as OP's [original file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/al2helal/ThesisWork/master/consecutive7pointDown10.input) doesn't grantee that, so this doesn't answer his/her question.

Comment: @αғsнιη How it is not guaranteed? OP said: "I need to select rows having consecutive 7 columns with value less than 10." If the number is less than 10, then one digit is guaranteed. May be negative numbers will be the problem, like `-7`, `-5`.

Comment: @αғsнιη Oh, file. I look at it, now. Then, yes, pattern should be corrected. But it is easy, I think. I thought, only integers (whole numbers) are possible.

Comment: @MiniMax then write for floating.

Comment: @alhelal See EDIT section.