# How to pass optional arguments to `time` command

Tags: bash, time

`man time` shows it has some options, like this, to write just the `time` output to a file instead of to `stderr`:

```bsh
-o FILE, --output=FILE
```

So, I try to use it

```bsh
$ time -o out.txt ls
-o: command not found

real    0m0.081s
user    0m0.070s
sys 0m0.012s
```

This does not work! It says `-o: command not found`.

To prove `out.txt` doesn't exist:

```bsh
$ cat out.txt
cat: out.txt: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I use options like `-o somefile.txt` with `time`?

I am on Linux Ubuntu 18.04, using `bash` as my terminal.

Comment: Yes it looks like even the example quoted in the manpage fails `time -a -o log emacs bork`

Comment: You have to specify ... what time is it. Use `command time` or `/usr/bin/time` see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10747/216907

Comment: Your question probably can be linked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86266/make-bash-use-external-time-command-rather-than-shell-built-in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bash shell is evaluating the first word "time" in your command as the reserved word `time` and is waiting for a command at the second word, which is `-o`, so it's printing: `-o: command not found`.

At [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) we can see the reason `time` is a reserved word:

> The use of time as a reserved word permits the timing of shell
> builtins, shell functions, and pipelines. An external time command
> cannot time these easily.

In order to use the `time` command, and use its useful arguments, you have to instruct the bash shell so. It is better to do it using the `command` utility:

```
command time -o out.txt ls
```

Or you could use the full path:

```
/usr/bin/time -o out.txt ls
```

Or even quote it:

```
"time" -o out.txt ls
```

Or escape it with a backslash:

```
\time -o out.txt ls
```

See also posts: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86266/216907) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10745/216907)

Comment: This is quite informative. Thank you for providing multiple solutions.